# what happens to my first insertion in sqlite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, insert, sqliteopenhelper

#### Summary

Using android studio and sqlite database, I'm trying to insert some rows to a table. the problem is when I wanna read them, it ignores the first row.

#### Codes

first insert 3 rows to `DATASETS_INFO` table:

```
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String query = "INSERT INTO `DATASETS_INFO`(`dataset_ID`, `dataset_name`, `type`, `RAPI`) " +
                "VALUES (122, 'avg temp salon 2', 1, '3avwVmZpw00')";
        db.execSQL(query);

        query = "INSERT INTO `DATASETS_INFO`(`dataset_ID`, `dataset_name`, `type`, `RAPI`) " +
                "VALUES (125, 'avg hum salon 2', 2, '75uNfLLy300')";
        db.execSQL(query);

        query = "INSERT INTO `DATASETS_INFO`(`dataset_ID`, `dataset_name`, `type`, `RAPI`) " +
                "VALUES (126, 'max hum salon 2', 2, 'b8rwdUM4F00')";
        db.execSQL(query);
```

---

then reading them:

```
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "Select dataset_name, type FROM DATASETS_INFO";
        Cursor myCursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        Log.d("DatabaseHelper", "myCursor.getCount(): " + myCursor.getCount());
        DatasetInfo[] datasetInfos = new DatasetInfo[myCursor.getCount()];
        if (myCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int i=0;
            while (myCursor.moveToNext()) {
                Log.d("DatabaseHelper", "i: " + i + ", dataset_name: " + myCursor.getString(0));
                datasetInfos[i] = new DatasetInfo();
                datasetInfos[i].dataset_name = myCursor.getString(0);
                datasetInfos[i].type = myCursor.getInt(1);
                ++i;
            }
        }
```

---

output:
as u can see it ignores the first row and starts from the second row:

```
07-24 10:38:06.317 7253-7253/com.example.black3rror.mpandroidchart D/DatabaseHelper: myCursor.getCount(): 3
07-24 10:38:06.317 7253-7253/com.example.black3rror.mpandroidchart D/DatabaseHelper: i: 0, dataset_name: avg hum salon 2
07-24 10:38:06.317 7253-7253/com.example.black3rror.mpandroidchart D/DatabaseHelper: i: 1, dataset_name: max hum salon 2
```

its interesting that getCount() returns 3 but I don't know where is the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why 1st record is skipped is that you are calling `moveToFirst()` and then without reading it (which is the first record), you are calling `moveToNext()`. So the first record is skipped between these calls.

`moveToFirst()` is used when you need to start iterating from the start after you have already reached some position. In your case, you are already at the first position. Following should work:

```
int i = 0;
  do  {
   Log.d("DatabaseHelper", "i: " + i + ", dataset_name: " + myCursor.getString(0));
        datasetInfos[i] = new DatasetInfo();
        datasetInfos[i].dataset_name = myCursor.getString(0);
        datasetInfos[i].type = myCursor.getInt(1);
        ++i;
} while (myCursor.moveToNext());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use do while loop

```
          do {
            Log.d("DatabaseHelper", "i: " + i + ", dataset_name: " + myCursor.getString(0));
            datasetInfos[i] = new DatasetInfo();
            datasetInfos[i].dataset_name = myCursor.getString(0);
            datasetInfos[i].type = myCursor.getInt(1);
            ++i;
        } while (myCursor.moveToNext());
```

Comment: huh. you are right. that stupid `while` structure was because of copy-pasting from the net. thanx